# Проблемы с animation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь помощью jquery сделать следующие: сначала отрабатывает эффект FadeIn, потом callback-функцией вызывается анимация, изменяющая opacity и transform у другого элемента. Следом нужно плавно изменить прозрачность блока и включить фоновое видео. Вот что получилось:

```html
<script>
  $(function ($) {
   $( "#image-svg" ).fadeIn ( 2000, function () {
    $(".main h1").animate({
     "opacity":"1",
     "transform":"translate3d(0, 100px, 0)"}, 1500, function () {
     $(".main-block").css ('background', "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)");
     $(".video-bg-1").get(0).play();
    });
   });
  });
 </script>
```

Первая проблема с transform - не отрабатывает. Opacity работает, а трансформация нет. И вторая проблема: как сделать плавность изменения фона? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.animate поддерживает анимацию только численных значений, о чем сказано в документации:

> The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any
>   numeric CSS property. The only required parameter is a plain object of
>   CSS properties. This object is similar to the one that can be sent to
>   the .css() method, except that the range of properties is more
>   restrictive.

**Решение 1**

Использовать [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

```
.main h1 {
    transition: transform 1.5s linear;
}
```

После чего просто выставляйте значение CSS свойства

```
$('.main h1').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, 100px, 0)');
```

**Решение 2**

Использовать подобный трюк

```
$('.main h1').animate({
    opacity: 1
}, {
    duration: 1500,
    step: function(x) {
        // x - значение свойства opacity в определенный момент времени
        // которое растет от 0 (если по-умолчанию оно было 0) до 1 (как мы указали выше)
        $(this).css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + (x * 100) + 'px, 0)');
    },
    done: function() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Для плавного изменения фона ситуация аналогичная

Comment: Спасибо! Первый способ помог.